# Javascript prompt within a function not returning the value I expect

Tags: javascript

```
var perimeterBox = function(length, width) {
    return (length * 2) + (width * 2);
};

var justAsk = prompt("what is the length, width?");

perimeterBox(justAsk);
```

When I run it the prompt pops up. However when I enter the length, width (ex:7,3) I get a value of null. Thought?

Comment: `prompt` does return the string `"7, 3"`. Your `perimeterBox` function is expecting two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the values from the string inputted by the user:

```
var perimeterBox = function(length, width) {
    return (length * 2) + (width * 2);
};

var justAsk = prompt("what is the length, width?"); // justAsk is "7,3"

var values = justAsk.match(/\d+/g); // values is ["7", "3"]
var width = parseInt(values[0]); // width is 7
var height = parseInt(values[1]); // height is 3

perimeterBox(width, height);
```

Comment: I like this... however, the `parseInt` isn't necessary, because the `*` in the `perimeterBox` function will coerce the type to be an int regardless, and the `/\d+/` ensures it will never be anything but an int.

Comment: Also there is some danger of the user entering `"4.5, 7.6"` and it breaking because it will only pull out `4` and `5`.

Comment: `/\d+(?:\.\d*?)/g` would account for that I think.

Comment: I agree with all comments, but for a developer who has trouble understanding how parameters are passed to functions, i think they are too complicated. I added the parseInt to show that before it value was a string. I put the regexp as simple as possible. Clarity > covering all cases for theoretical/learning questions.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm a week into Javascript so I have a basically everything to learn.